# Error 405: Method Not Supported

Tags: php, html, email, tor

I'm making a tor website that people can report sites to us (CP etc) and we will remove them. We are using an html form that submits via POST to php and then it E-Mails us the information.
The problem I'm getting is:

```
Error 405: Method Not Supported
Only GET and HEAD requests supported for this resource.
```

Here is the code i am using:
HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Report site - Tor's anti-terrorism campaign.</title>
<style>
h1
{
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:36px;
    color:#060;
}
h2
{
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#C33;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Report a site on Tor for us to hopefully take down</h1>
<h2>Sites that are listed as inappropriate material for us are:</h2>
<h2>Child pornography</h2>
<h2>Terrorist sites</h2>
<h2>Piracy sites <i>that contain child pornography or terrorist material</i></h2>
<hr />
<h2 style="color:#030"><B>Things that are actually OK:</B></h2>
<h2 style="color:#030">Black markets</h2>
<h2 style="color:#030">Copyrighted material</h2>
<h2 style="color:#030">Piracy sites</h2>
<br />
<p>Any other site you would like to report please enquire about at CONTACT INFO.</p>
<hr />
<form method="post" action="form_handler.php" name="Report">
    <p>
    <input type="hidden" name="derive_fields" value="email=EmailAddr,realname=FullName">
    <br />
    <br />
    Contact E-Mail Address:
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="thats@riseup.net" size="50">
    <br />
    <br />
    First Name(Put anonymous to not be named): 
    <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="John" size="50">
    <br />
    <br />
    .Onion address or web address: 
    <input type="text" name="onion" placeholder="e.g. dwonbdbwqdb3.onion" size="50">
    </p>
    <p>
      Name of organization (if known): <input type="text" name="org" placeholder="organization name" size="31.75">
    </p>
    <p>
      What is it?<select name="Type" multiple="multiple" size="5">
        <option value="Terrorism">Terrorism</option>
        <option value="CP">Child porn</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="rc-button rc-button-submit">
    </p>  
</form></body>
</html>
```

And the PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "thats@riseup.net";
    $from = $_POST['email'];
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $subject = "Form submission";
    $onion = $_POST['onion'];
    $org = $_POST['org'];
    $type = $_POST['Type'];
    $message = $first_name . "Here is the stats for the form submitted about the site"  $onion . " " . $org . " " . $type;
    mail($to,$subject,$message);
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ";
    }
?>
```

Any help would be good!
Thanks
The html was made half by me and half by my friend and I completely wrote all the PHP so it will be the PHP which is probably wrong :)

Comment: is it hosted on an onion site? maybe it's them not allowing the resource, code looks alright

Comment: @Billy Yes the site is hosted on an onion site, that could be the problem. Is there a way I could get it to send to the email address from an onion site?

Comment: don't know much about it, it looks like it's not 'sending the email' that's the problem but the POST. option 1 ) try changing the form and $_posts to get and see if it works. 2 ) try commenting out all the php and try just `mail("thats@riseup.net","test","test message");

Comment: @Billy How would i test option 2?

Comment: make the php file just `<?php mail("thats@riseup.net","test","test message"); ?>`

Comment: Pressed submit on the html page after editing the php and I get the same error. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What about I use GET and HEAD (quoting from the error message) but i have no idea what that means

Comment: did you change the method to get on the form? try typing the php url direct into the browser and see if you get an email

Comment: it means this `<form method="post" action="form_handler.php" name="Report">` try changing it to `<form method="get" action="form_handler.php" name="Report">`

Comment: i have been using my phone to access this site but it is downloading the php file instead of submitting to it. I cannot use my laptop as i am hosting it from there so cannot use tor browser too

Comment: are you running a server? it shouldn't download php...

Comment: My phone downloads the php file. I'm using chrome on a rooted android device using orbot. check.torproject.org tells me I am using tor on it. Is there any chance we could use skype instead?

Comment: don't use skype, never heard of orbot and don't know much about tor.... So that be a no. I suggest you do a question in the Tor section for further help